# Which Push Notification caused the app to resume from the background

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

My App receives `APNS Push Notifications`, and when a user receive more than one `NSNotification`, he should be able to open the app in a specific view according the `NSNotification` tapped.

So in the method

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application 
        didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo 
        fetchCompletionHandler:
           (void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
```

I added this code to save all the notifications

```
if (self.notifications == nil) {
        self.notifications = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

    [notifications addObject:userInfo];
```

And every time the app becomes active again it does this

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) 
    // while the application was inactive.
    // If the application was previously in the background, 
    // optionally refresh the user interface.
    [notifications removeAllObjects];
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}
```

Before removing all the objects and setting the badge to zero, I would like to handle which `NSNotification` made my app open from the background. And once I have which push `NSNotification` it was, I would like to pass all the data to a specific view.

Comment: Should you be using `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` or `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:`? What problem are you seeing?

Comment: The APNS Push Notification is used to launch some code and push local notifications. When user open one of these local notification I would like to open specific views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Based on your comment about `UILocalNotification` usage*

`UILocalNotification` has a `userInfo` property. When you create your local notification from the push notification, set the appropriate information into this property and then when the app delegate receives `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` you can use that into to update your UI.

Comment: When my app is in background and a local notification resume my app from background I just want to know how I catch what local notification opened my app (if there are more than one local notification).

Comment: `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:`

Answer (score 0):

If you not use new iOS7 background fetch notifications.

In `- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application` before removing all object from notification array, check for notification

```
NSDictionary * myNotification = [notifications lastObject]; 
if (myNotification)
{
 // is last notification 
}
```

Is will work because app receive only notification that user tap on it

Comment: The problem is that if the user receives 3 push notifications and he is insterested only in the second one and he taps on it. How can i know that is the second notification that resumed my app?

Comment: in this case how many objects you have in `notifications` array ?

Comment: In notifications array I save every notifications arrive until the user open the app. When the user open the app clear my notifications variable. If user receive 3 local notifications how could I understand what of the 3 resumed my app from background?

Comment: I think app not receive any notification until user tap on one of them, but you can run app, check it and update question with new info

Answer (score 0):

Send with your push notification, data, and use it when your app receives it.

In this example, i'm using the image file and alert, and sending it to all the views that are registered for this Notification.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{

    //Posting the notificaiton to the use, if its valid:

    NSDictionary *returnDic = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];


    if (![returnDic objectForKey:@"alert"]) {
        return;
    }
    NSString *alert = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[returnDic objectForKey:@"alert"]];

    if (![returnDic objectForKey:@"MagnetID"]) {
        return;
    }

    NSString *magnetImage = [returnDic objectForKey:@"MagnetImage"];

    NSDictionary *dictionaryToSend = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:magnetImage,MAGNET_IMAGE,alert,MAGNET_ERROR_MESSEGE, nil];


    //Posting to the rest of the views, the messege:

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:USER_MESSEGE_RECEAVED object:nil userInfo:dictionaryToSend];

    NSLog(@"Notifications - userInfo=%@",userInfo);


}
```

What you may do, is save the data that you need, by UserDefults or whatever you prefer, and at the "applicationDidBecomeActive" method, use that data to show the right view.

Hope this helps